# TypeScript functional shared instantiation

Tags: typescript

Is there some canonical way to type functional shared instantiation in TypeScript, such we can do something like:

```
const indexableMethods = {
  valueAt(index: number) {
    return this.array[index]; // Property 'array' does not exist on type '{ valueAt(index: number): any; }'
  },
};

function asIndexable<T extends { array: unknown[] }>(object: T) {
  return Object.assign(object, indexableMethods);
}

const foo = asIndexable({ array: [1, 2, 3] });
console.log(foo.valueAt(1)) // 2;
```

One problem seems to be using `this.array` in `indexableMethods`. I've tried moving the method definitions inside the assigning function, however, I still have a problem with not being to infer the return type of `valueAt` properly:

```
function asIndexable<T extends { array: unknown[] }>(object: T) {
  return Object.assign(object, {
    valueAt(index: number) {
      return object.array[index];
    },
  });
}

const x = asIndexable({ array: [1, 2, 3] }).valueAt(1) // x: unknown
```

Adding a generic parameter (`asIndexable<T, U extends { array: T[] }>(...)`) does not seem to help either.

Is there any to add functionality to objects like this while retaining type information?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand what are you trying to do, but you can set type of [`this` explicitly](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#specifying-the-type-of-this-for-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does the trick, where I have specified the return type of `valueAt` explicitly, otherwise the inferred return type would be `unknown` which is simply the broadest type TS can use in that context:

```
function asIndexable<T extends { array: unknown[] }>(object: T) {
  type V = typeof object["array"][number];
  return Object.assign(object, {
    valueAt(index: number): V {
      return object.array[index];
    },
  });
}

const a = asIndexable({ array: [1, 2, 3], b: 1 });
// const a: { array: number[]; b: number;} & { valueAt(index: number): number; }

const x = asIndexable({ array: [1, 2, 3], b: true }).valueAt(1);
// const x: number

const y = asIndexable({ array: [1, 2, 3], b: true }).array[1];
// const y: number

const z = asIndexable({ array: ["1", "2", "3"], b: 1 }).valueAt(1);
// const z: string

const e = asIndexable({ array: ["1", "2", 3], b: 1 }).valueAt(1);
// const e: string | number
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM4EkwBMCmAPZAIwBscAeAFUXyh21UQG8UAnF5ATwC5FwBrMHADuYANoBdRAF8AfAAo4hAFY5oPCgEomAKESIoHAA45EANUQBefUZxxgiRSuiiARMjacX40WBABbQhwWcQBuXUQWHCgQFiQAeWVVKAA6NFQYAHMwBUToABodPT0AN2RiEBwAQSg5GGx8Hl8AoI0ec0ZwooiomKRHJNSPDlE63DxQzuk88KkNMKltbQgEVCgUSxQMeoISHDlmd3ZuRFEARgKAJgKAZnECwh5T6TntAHpXxGWwVZQeA6HGv5AiwJCFEA9EE1gSEpIgAGRMRClcpVGqjBqQoEtQHNFhghZLFZrPAbNCYMZEUj7VhHHhnS43O7gnhQFgVZ7JZEVapyU4vd6fImIPA44GLL4-DikrYU3bUw6cOnnRBXRC3e4stkmWaDI5nCYCiVrY5QoLioUAL2l5PwlL2-1pJxcpxcBRcF1diBc1y8GsQTx1XNRvP5HyNiAtPFWLDqGXN3zWJisZO2dvlAKdLrdHsZfoDGk5ZW5NT5YUNQpwUdZscQAB9MbjtEA)